# Static vs. dynamic event attachments on HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, events

As the title may be slightly ambiguous or not clear, I'll first explain what I mean by the two methods.  In my HTML/JS code, I mix two ways of attaching events to my html elements: (1) what I call "static":

```
<input name="abc" class="def" id="xyz" onclick="do_something"/>
```

and (2) what I call "dynamic":

```
<input name="abc" class="def" id="xyz" />
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#xyz').click(function() { do_something; })
});
```

Note that this is not a real code, just something to present as an example.  I don't have to use jquery either, the same could be achieve with simple

```
document.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('xyz').onclick = function() { do_something; }
}
```

Usually if the logic is quite simple (e.g. enable/disable on element on click of another), I would use static method.  If the logic is more complicated, I would use dynamic one.  Of course, I can also use static method with `onclick="function_call()"` - and put all the complicated logic into this function, although this is something I may have left in the code from legacy days (from years ago).

Now, I have met people that would swear by one of the methods and deride anybody that would use the other, claiming that the other method is wrong/difficult-to-read/slower/add-your-own-explanation.  HoweverI have not found any really good reason to always stick with one method and keep mixing these up.  Am I missing something or is there really no good reason to stick with one method?

Comment: Don't you just love people that downvote without any indication of the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My practice is to follow **the rule of least surprise**.

If my page is 99% HTML and just 1 or 2 lines of Javascript then I use inline events `<div onclick="">` to minimize the amount of fluff in the page due to addEventListener baggage.

If my page is too complex with too many elements and if separation of behavior will cause large chunks of `getElementById` or `$('.tree')` sections, which actually inhibits resadability (therefore increases surprise level) then I also use inline event. How and why

Otherwise I use the expected separation of structure and behavior rule.

Answer (score 6):

You ***should*** separate structure (HTML), style (CSS) and behavior (JS).

Events are ***behaviors*** of the page - do it in JS.

***Don't*** place them anywhere else, not in the HTML, not in the CSS (if ever it were possible).

Answer (score 2):

Static:

- mixes logic with content
- only supports the old (and not formally specified) "DOM0" event model
- doesn't allow binding multiple handlers to an event - you *should* be using DOM2 `addEventListener()`, not `.onXXX()`
- complicates syntax because of quote mixing - you may have to escape quotes to avoid clashing with the quotes in the `onXXX` attribute.

Comment: For what it's worth, an event handler attribute has the advantage of working as soon as the element is rendered rather than having to wait until the event handler is attached.